# Get URL with virtual directory included?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am maintaining an ASP.NET Web Forms website **(and I do mean website, it's not a web application)**, and some of the static links are broken because they are hosting it with a virtual directory.

```
http://www.somewhere.com/MyApp
```

So, I started down the path to find a way to get an absolute URL given a virtual path to some page. And I found an article that mentioned you could take a link like this:

```
<a href="/ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a>
```

and do something like this:

```
<a href="<%= System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("/ContactUs.aspx") %>">Contact Us</a>
```

but that's not even working locally **(i.e. against the ASP.NET Development Server)** because my local path might be something like this:

```
http://localhost:7766/MyApp
```

but the path yielded by the `VirtualPathUtility` is this:

```
http://localhost:7766/ContactUs.aspx
```

---

So, I decided to deploy it to my local IIS instance and see how it would behave. And the outcome was the same. The local IIS path is:

```
http://localhost/MyApp
```

but the path to the contact us page is:

```
http://localhost/ContactUs.aspx
```

---

One final hitch in the get along, there is one link in the application that looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="ContactUsLink"
    runat="server"
    Enabled="true"
    NavigateUrl="/ContactUs.aspx"
    Text="Contact Us">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

and the reason I say it's a hitch in the get along is because I know the inline code **(like the examples above)** don't work on server controls. It actually throws a compiler error:

> Server tags cannot contain <% ... %> constructs.

---

So it appears I'm clearly moving down the wrong path, and I need some help. I'm looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```

Answer (score 2):

You should prefix your addresses with a ~.   so   "~/Contact.aspx" on any runat=server control.   This won't work for a standard  tag.   You can add runat=server to a normal  tag to make it a server control.

The runtime will see the ~ and make it relative to what you're running as.

```
<asp:HyperLink id="ContactUsLink"
    runat="server"
    Enabled="true"
    NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx"
    Text="Contact Us">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ~ that will resolve your URL correctly, so, your HyperLink control becomes this:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="ContactUsLink"
    runat="server"
    Enabled="true"
    NavigateUrl="~/ContactUs.aspx"
    Text="Contact Us">
</asp:HyperLink>
```

The ~ sign will always resolve to the root directory of your application and it'll take into account the virtual path for you so. The above solution will also get rid of the need for server tags so should solve your problem.

If you want to get the virtual directory path (i.e. the MyApp part of your URL) directly in code for whatever reason, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` that will return the virtual path for you. You can then use that to derive your URL.

Comment: The ~ is essential!

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.protocol + "/" +(window.location.host + "/" + window.location.pathname);
```